# Forward Contract Price on Zero Coupon Bond

Tags: fixed-income, finance, finance-mathematics, financial-engineering

[image]**I'm trying to calculate the forward contract on a zero coupon bond where the forward contract matures at t=4.**
The zero coupon bond matures at t=10 and has a face value of 100. The price of that bond is 61.62

$n=10-period$ binomial model for the short-rate
The lattice parameters are: 
$r(0,0) = 5\%, u = 1.1, d = 0.9d, q = 0.5, 1−q = 0.5$

Comment: Not sure why you are using a binomial lattice to price a forward.  There is no optionality in a forward.

Comment: This was given to me for an assignment. I've added my calculations from the provided workbooks

Comment: Looks very much like the coursera course on financial engineering by Haugh and Iyengar. :)      @AlRacoon the tree is needed to model the stochastic short rate

Comment: @KeSchn you are correct! I have calculated the ZCB price and futures contract price but am stuck on the forward contract

Comment: i'm stuck too, did you find the answer? i find at T=0 F=90,85 So the forward price should be 147,43 because the Face value of the Bond is 100 or am i missing something? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the forward price $F$ of a zero coupon bond at t=4, note that arbitrage considerations imply that $$Z(0,10)= Z(0,4) F$$.   This essentially means that investing in a 4 year zero coupon bond together with a forward contract to invest from year 4 to  year 10 must be the same as investing in a 10 year bond.  So you need to first calculate Z(0,4) from your lattice.

Comment: Given that the above is basically a no-arbitrage from spot/forward yields (directly linked to ZCB), would you mind expanding briefly if/how this would work for coupon/corporate bonds?